# Ensure unique field value in loopback model

Tags: json, node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

How to ensure uniqueness of a particular field in loopback model.
Like below is the model Post, I have a field genericId in it, I want it to be unique in the database, and loopback to through an error, on duplicate key insertion.

```
{
  "name": "Post",
  "plural": "Post",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "genericId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required":True 
    },
    "moderatedAt": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

I have tried searching there documentation, and other examples but no success.
One solution which I can think of is, to create a remoteHook for the create function, and validate this field before inserting, but looking for some other way.

Comment: you can also enforce uniqueness on your database directly

Comment: Yes, Strongloop's LoopbackJS documentation is impossibly miserable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set [validation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Validating+model+data) rule in your `common/models/post.js`

```
Post.validatesUniquenessOf('genericId');
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but have already got it, sorry forgot to update it here.

Comment: Correct validation docs https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Validating+model+data

Comment: Only supported connectors: In Memory, Oracle or MongoDB

Comment: What if I want to keep combination of fields to be unique?

Answer (score 30):

Not sure if it is the better way to achieve uniqueness, but [you can find here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Indexes) the docs about indexing your model.

Just add a unique index on the field you want, and voila !

For your model, that would be :

```
{
  ...
    "genericId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": True,
      "index": {"unique": true} 
    },
 ...
}
```

However, if the `genericId` field is the actual Id of the model, I suggest you declare it as such, so you can use `findById` method, and also avoid creation of a duplicate `id` field, which will happen if you don't declare any in your model.

```
{
  ...
    "genericId": {
      "type": "string", 
      "id": true,       // Ensure uniqueness and avoid another model id field
      "generated": true // Add this if you want Loopback to manage id content for you
    },
 ...
}
```

Comment: Could you expend on "...declare it as such"? Thanks.

Comment: *Note: this is an old post, not sure if its still valid*. In the above message, the code expands on the explanation : you declare a field as a model ID by setting the `id` prop (to `true`) in the field json definition.

Answer (score 10):

The Lookback v4 solution looks like this:

```
@model()
export class Client extends Entity {

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true,
    },
  })
  name: string;

}
```

Then you must update your schema:

```
npm run migrate
```

or recreate it:

```
npm run migrate -- --rebuild
```

Comment: Did you update your schema? `npm run migrate` or `npm run migrate -- --rebuild`?

Comment: Not every connector might support this. I checked it for PostgreSQL. MySQL is supported, too, I guess.

Comment: Thank you Mathias, this is what I've been looking for. Tested in PostgreSQL. Btw, it doesn't send a good error message for the response. The error response now would only be 500. Does any of you have reference for editing that? Thank you!

Comment: This answer is more elegant and also correct one for Mongo Driver, in my opinion