# I can't set unique field in Loopback ORM model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, loopbackjs, unique-constraint

I'm new in Loopback 3.
And I need to define the model with the unique field.
Email field should be unique. I'm using Postgresql as DB.

I have tried adding "unique": true option. Also, I have tried to follow these pieces of advice: [Ensure unique field value in loopback model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927961/ensure-unique-field-value-in-loopback-model). But it didn't give the desired result.

```
 "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "bigint"
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "character varying"
      }
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "varchar",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "character varying"
      }
    },
    "added_date": {
      "type": "date",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "date"
      }
    }
  }
```

In the end result, I want to have a unique field in Postgres scheme.
It should look like this in Postgres :

```
-- Table: public."user"

-- DROP TABLE public."user";

CREATE TABLE public."user"
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    added_date date,
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_email_key UNIQUE (email)

)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."user"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these will work.  Either add the `index` property to the column def, or add it to the indexes portion of the model.  It's weird there isn't more documentation on this.

```
 "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "bigint"
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "character varying"
      }
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "varchar",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "character varying"
      }
    },
    "added_date": {
      "type": "date",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "date"
      }
    }
  },
  "indexes": {
    "EMAIL_INDEX": {
      "columns": "email",
      "kind": "unique"
    }
  }
```

Or alternatively

```
 "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "bigint"
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "character varying"
      }
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "varchar",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "character varying"
      },
      "index": {"kind": "UNIQUE"}
    },
    "added_date": {
      "type": "date",
      "postgresql": {
        "dataType": "date"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank for an answer, but it doesn't work in mine case. I should integrate my ORM model with PostgreSQL schemes that are using ```UNIQUE CONSTRAINT```, not ```UNIQUE INDEX```. As a solution, I have created ```UNIQUE CONSTRAINT``` after ```autoupdate``` or ```automugration```.