# enforcing uniqueness in loopback4 model's properties

Tags: loopback4

I started to run a simple hello world project using lb4. I created a basic mongodb datasource, and a repository and a simple model (username, password and id) for users with cli command provided by loopback. I also created a user controller, with a built in crud choice provided by loopback. 
as you may know, this is a very basic setup but if anyone needs details, I will provide, just comment.
the problem is that, when I try to make new users using explorer, I encounter with duplicate same username models. means that:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5def4581f7f9d508b0da2d4c"),
"username" : "string",
"password" : "string"
}
```

and:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5def4584f7f9d508b0da2d4d"),
"username" : "string",
"password" : "string"
}
```

the client should enter unique username for signup. that's obvious. 
**how can I specify uniqueness of a property of a model in loopback 4 (without declaring it as id)?**

Comment: there is a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927961/ensure-unique-field-value-in-loopback-model but it's for version 3 not 4.

Comment: Yes. Does that fulfill your requirement?

Comment: since lb3 is on js and lb4 is typescript I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to this [issue on github](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3258), lb4 already checks for duplicates inside of its context using indexes and 11000 error code of mongoDB (I am talking about [shopping example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback4-example-shopping), not a simple `lb4 app` so **BE AWARE!** If you want you can implement uniqueness using description below). What I forgot to do was database migration ‍. 
you can do database migration with this command: 
`npm run migrate` 
so the complete answer should be like this:
1- inside the model add this: (change uniqueEmail and email to property name you want to be unique)

```
@model({
    settings: {
        indexes: {
          uniqueEmail: {
            keys: {
              email: 1,
            },
            options: {
              unique: true,
            },
         },
    },
  },
})
```

2- check inside of the controller, the endpoint you want to check uniqueness, and add a try catch to catch error of uniqueness which came from your mongoDB datasource:

```
try {
  // In my case create the new user, but can be anything you want
  const savedUser = await this.userRepository.create(
    _.omit(newUserRequest, 'password'),
  );

  // do stuff and return

} catch (error) {
  // MongoError 11000 duplicate key
  if (error.code === 11000 && error.errmsg.includes('index: uniqueEmail')) {
    throw new HttpErrors.Conflict('Email value is already taken');
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

3- run `npm run migrate`

This answer now is a general answer which can be used for any property of any model.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, you said you would define uniqueness in your `model`. And here you have done `filtering` and nothing else!

Comment: Exactly! what I wanted to do is to declare property as "unique" not filter the results and check them. But I found nothing. If any answer shows the solution inside of models declaration, accepted as the correct answer and I will remove mine.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what i found out that `Loopback4` has a property called **`name`**  which a unique identifier for the authentication strategy ( for example : ‘basic’, ‘jwt’, etc). You can look into more detailed manner  [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.authentication.authenticationstrategy.name.html) **AND** [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.authentication.authenticationstrategy.html)

You should change the `username` to `name` so as to fulfill your requirement.
Because that's how it works in **`loopback4`**

Comment: this solution will work fine for usernames. but what about a model that is not part of the authentication? how can restrict "any" property of a model not to be duplicate?