# How to add a unique constraints through Loopback 4 Model?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

I have a `Department` model in my project. The properties are `id`, `name`. `name` of course should be unique. However I can't seem to look where the setting is so I can put something like

```js
@model()
export class Department extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id?: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    unique: true // ---> This is what I want. But how?
  })
  name: string;

  constructor(data?: Partial<Department>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

I tried digging to [Model](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html) documentation, it seems that there is something I can do with the `@model` decorator. However I found no documentation about it.

Also, I want to do this in PostgreSQL as a datasource. Any clue? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to set this as a duplicate, but the answer is here, [Ensure unique field value in loopback model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927961/ensure-unique-field-value-in-loopback-model?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

@property({
type: 'string',
required: true,
**index: {
unique: true,
}**
})
name: string;

Using index object.

Migrate Database - Modify or alter table

run command : **npm run build**
migrate database : **npm run migrate**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).